# Is there a nice way to programmatically call the file auto-detection algorithm?

Tags: vimscript, filetype

I was writing a simple Vim plug-in for a generic code generator called [Templaty](https://github.com/samvv/Templaty). The generator can theoretically work with any programming language, and I'd like Vim to automatically apply the correct highlighting.

From experiments, I have noticed Vim automatically loads the correct highlighter if I do something like `set ft=c.templaty`. Now, I was wondering if there's a generic way to auto-detect the first part of this string. Right now, I brute-force it by keeping track of a small dictionary of file extensions and their corresponding file type, then doing `exec "setfiletype" (filetype . ".templaty")`, but this is far from ideal.

Vim already has `ftdetect`-logic, quite possibly with lots of user-defined ones. How would I be able to query this information programmatically?

**Edit:**

As suggested in the comments, I could just read `b:current_syntax`, but the problem is that the additional `.tply` file extension might prevent the default `ftdetect`-logic from working. Would it be possible to tell Vim to try detecting the correct file type *as if* the file was without the `.tply` extension?

Comment: Actually, your problem is that you `unlet b:current_syntax` inside your code. Just don't do this and you can read it afterwards.

Comment: Actually ... That's so simple that I totally forgot about it! Will try it out later today; thanks!

Comment: It looks like you may already have solved your problem, but in case you haven't, I have a question about `Now, I was wondering if there's a generic way to auto-detect the first part of this string.` Could you explain a bit more about the scenario in which you need to run auto-detection? Is there a buffer? Is it saved? Does it have contents?

Comment: @Rich I haven't had time to test it yet, but I believe the problem is solved with @Matt's comment. To answer your question, the logic should be in `ftdetect/`, so I suppose this is right after a file is loaded.

Comment: So you just wanted to know how to query the current filetype?

Comment: Acutally, that's a good question. I totally forgot that my file has an additional `.tply`-extension, which might prevent the default `ftdetect` from working correctly. I will update my question.

Comment: @samvv I'd write up the above as a proper answer, but I'm still not 100% clear on what your plugin does and when/how this code is going to be invoked.

Comment: @Rich That's a standard feature in Vim: if filetype is of the form `x.y.z` then Vim loads indents and syntaxes of `x`, then `y`, and then `z` in sequence. All one has to do is to use a "standard" thing for `x`, and then _not to overwrite_ b:current_syntax inside custom `y` and `z`. That's pretty much all to it.

Comment: @Matt Duh. I was aware of this when I _started_ commenting on this question, and somehow forgot while writing the above. I'll delete my inane comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the whole point is that if `&filetype` is of the form `x.y` then Vim automatically loads indents and syntaxes from *both* `x.vim` and `y.vim`.

Then the code in `syntax/y.vim` must take this into account and keep the previous value of `b:current_syntax`. So instead of usual: `if exists('b:current_syntax') | finish | endif`, or `unlet b:current_syntax` it should start with something like that:

```
if !exists('b:current_syntax')
    " cannot be the first syntax!
    finish
endif
" append the new syntax instead of overwriting it
let b:current_syntax .= '.y'
```

> As suggested in the comments, I could just read b:current_syntax, but the problem is that the additional .tply file extension might prevent the default ftdetect-logic from working. Would it be possible to tell Vim to try detecting the correct file type as if the file was without the .tply extension?

If you want to also make an auto-detection working then you have to write a file-detection script and put it under `ftdetect/` subdirectory (the file name does not matter, as detection scripts are always preloaded):

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead ?\+.tply
    \ exe 'doau filetypedetect BufRead' fnameescape(expand('<afile>:r')) |
    \ if did_filetype() |
    \     let &ft .= '.templaty' |
    \ endif
```

Note that filetype will be set twice, but it should not be important, as "standard" syntaxes/indents have a guard against double inclusion.

Comment: That last snippet is _exactly_ what I was looking for! Thank you so much! I'll try to integrate it in a patch tomorrow.